# Can I copy a recovery partition from an HD to an SSD?

Tags: macos, recovery

I installed an SSD in the optical bay of my mid-2009 MacBook Pro. I formatted it and copied most of the files from my HD and it works fine but wound up having no Recovery partition. I followed the instructions at [How can I create or recreate a Lion recovery partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19145/how-can-i-create-or-recreate-a-lion-recovery-partition) but at the end of the process I get this error:

```
Error (async): File system check on boot helper partition failed (-69840)
```

`diskutil list` shows me this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SteveBook2 SSD          239.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot                         650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SteveBook2 HD           749.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
```

So it looks like the SSD has a partition, but the Recovery HD is not installed. Is there any way to copy the Recovery partition from the HD to the SSD? I tried using Carbon Copy Cloner but got this:

[image: Carbon Copy Cloner screenshot]

I'm really hoping to be able to activate Find My Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

1. [What are the purposes and safety to enable the hidden debug menu in Disk Utility?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/enable-hidden-disk-image-formats-and-debug-menu-in-disk-utility)
2. Mount both recovery partitions
3. Select the HD's recovery partition and use Disk Utility's **Restore** function to copy it to the SSD's recovery partition
4. Boot from a USB drive and use the gpt remove/add commands as described at [Dmitry Dulepov's blog](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2011/09/how-to-create-mac-os-x-lion-recovery.html) to change the recovery partition's type from Apple_HFS to Apple_Boot. (Since the partition already existed at the correct size on my SSD I was able to skip the **Create a new partition** and **Fix recovery partition size** steps.)

```
   /dev/disk0
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
       1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS SteveBook2 SSD          239.2 GB   disk0s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD (SSD)       650.0 MB   disk0s3
    /dev/disk1
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk1
       1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS SteveBook2 HD           749.3 GB   disk1s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD (HD)        650.0 MB   disk1s3
```

Find My Mac is now enabled on my MacBook Pro.