# Is this fun partition mess I have made fixable on the Mac OS X side?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, partition

On a MacBook Pro, a wrong decision long time ago still causing numerous problems.

In a nut shell, I run bootcamp and OS X together on the same drive and the OS X stopped booting a while ago (I was trying to resize so that I make space for Win7). Today I fixed some issues but along the way, I messed up the boot system and moved to GPT (mistake!).

Here is my existing partition table:

```
    Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
      1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   AF00  EFI system partition
      2          409640          819239   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
      3          819240       300150351   142.7 GiB   AF00  Apple_HFS_Untitled_2
      4       300150352       301419887   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
      6       390352896       488396799   46.8 GiB    0700  BOOTCAMP
```

I like to solve the following problems:

1. Notice the number 5 that is missing, that is 50gb, recover this and make this seen from Win7.
2. Somehow see my main OS X partition from Win7 (this was the case before I move to GPT, now windows just says protected GPT)
3. Merge my existing 50G Bootcamp to the newly minted 50Gb so that I have a decent windows machine with a single drive letter.

Directions appreciated, especially 1 and 2 are more Mac specific, I think I can figure out 3, if I can solve 1 and 2.

**SOLVED**
I basically use the gpt application and there is an option that converts GTP to MBR. That solved the problem 1 and 2. http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/ is the tool I have used.

Comment: I want to add some general questions that might help an answerer: GUID (GPT) isn't bad necessarily - but the layout you have now will confuse bootcamp. You will certainly want to merge the windows partitions using a windows tool. Are you without backup or just hoping to live fix things and avoid re-loading things.

Comment: @bmike I don't mind wiping out OSx and reinstall from time machine but Windows must survive in its current form.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post it as a solution, and don't edit the solution into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I know in case it's relevant or helpful to you or someone else.

- Bootcamp is cranky with more than three partitions (the non-hidden partitions that you see in [Disk Utility without debug mode enabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/is-it-safe-to-enable-the-hidden-disk-image-formats-and-debug-menu-in-disk-utilit))
- You can always delete the Recovery HD and let the installer make it again.
- Disk Utility is good at live resizing volumes (especially on the Mac side) - if it doesn't offer to expand the size of the windows partition (after you delete the one that is free).
- Disk Utility is bad at moving / restoring non OS X data - yes it can move the bits, but it won't set EFI / BootLoader / other data needed for the OS to run. Better to use a windows tool for that end of things.