# What is the function(s) of the hidden Debug menu in Disk Utility?

Tags: disk-utility, filesystem, macos

What is the function(s) of the Debug menu and why is it hidden by default?

Comment: @jaume It has been hiding from you :)

Comment: It's also safe to enable in most cases… http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/is-it-safe-to-enable-the-hidden-disk-image-formats-and-debug-menu-in-disk-utilit?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Debug menu mostly gives access to functions in relation to hidden partitions (e.g. the system-restore-partition in Lion).  see [Debug Menu](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Enable-Disk-Utilitys-Debug-Menu.htm)

Most likely the Debug menu is mainly for Apple internal use (their techs dealing with stuff probably found these functions useful) so it's hidden by default.

Comment: Is it correct to say that it is rarely used therefore by most Apple users ?

Comment: Given that most Apple users would probably not know how to run the `defaults` command that enables it, I'd say that's safe to assume, yes.