# How To Enable The "Hidden" Debug Menu?

Tags: disk-utility

Following on from my previous question entitled ["What is the function(s) of the hidden Debug menu in Disk Utility?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96106/what-is-the-functions-of-the-hidden-debug-menu-in-disk-utility).

How do I enable the Debug Menu via Terminal command or otherwise, thereby increasing the functionality of Disk Utility ?

Comment: I don't understand, the answer provided in the previous question says how to turn on the Debug menu. Additionally, you can also use `DiskUtil` from terminal to get full functionality.

Comment: @hoss I thought that if someone was googling how to enable the debug menu this would show in the results (might be wrong though). Whereas the title of the other question was its function.

Comment: @hoss I will agree that a link to enablement was provided in the answer to my previous question (without my asking for it - although goes hand in hand I suppose).

Comment: This is good - it will be linked with the other two questions so anyone searching exactly for this will find the threads we have on debug and Disk Utility

Comment: @bmike Ok Fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk Utility starting in Mac OS ElCapitan (10.11, released in 2015) was completely redesigned and this feature does exist.

For the Disk Utility version in Mac OS Yosemite (10.10) and earlier:

1. Quit Disk Utility if it's open.
2. Open the Terminal application in `/Applications/Utilities`.
3. Type this exact command and hit Enter key:

   `defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1`
4. Quit the Terminal application.
5. Launch Disk Utility and you will have a the Debug menu.

Comment: Seems not to work in El Captain 10.11.4

Comment: Still not working in 10.11.6

Comment: doesn't work for me on MacOS ventura 13.4

Comment: Updated to clarify this was relevant in 2013, before the release of Mac OS 10.11 and later versions.